# usage of mount -o remount,exec /tmp Hbase hadoop file system and solr

Tags: command-line, server, mount, hadoop, solr

Can you please tell me what is main work of this command
mount -o remount,exec /tmp

I am using it when my hbase giving some errors but i don't know what  is happening using this command.
and i want know about /tmp directory , it is using whole directory or some folder in that particular directory?

my main doubt is one of my colleage wants to know that i am using this folder /tmp/hadoop-aemadmin/ or not?
I am handling nutch hbase and solr but i am not sure in backend this folder is used or not and one more thing i used that command in which /tmp mentioned that's why i am confused may be using this above command , this folder is used
Can anyone guide me ? how to identify this folder is used or not?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know /tmp/ should not be executable. This is one of the reasons why you should have a seperate /tmp/ partition with the noexec option.

The intention of the command `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` is to remount ( your temp folder/partiton) /tmp/ as executable. This should be avoided. You do not want files in /tmp to be executable.

/tmp/ stores temporary files that might have been downloaded from the web during the user session.

From a security standpoint, I doubt it is a good idea to run that command.

Comment: I got your point Thanks
Can you tell me can we clean /tmp/hadoop/ folder it is giving me no space left on server system.
We are running this command in live project from last 2 year.

Comment: I don't know. I guess you can. Perhaps rename beforehand. But **i am no expert**